# Unix : script as proxy to a file

Tags: file, unix, proxy

Hi : Is there a way to create a file which, when read, is generated dynamically ?

I wanted to create 3 versions of the same file (one with 10 lines, one with 100 lines, one with all of the lines).  Thus, I don't see any need for these to be static, but rather, it would be best if they were proxies from a head/tail/cat command.

*The purpose of this is for unit testing - I want a unit test to run on a small portion of the full input file used in production.  However, since the code only runs on full files (its actually a hadoop map/reduce application), I want to provide a truncated version of the whole data set without duplicating information.*

**UPDATE: An Example**

```
more myActualFile.txt 

1
2
3
4
5

more myProxyFile2.txt 

1
2

more myProxyFile4.txt 

1
2
3
4
```

etc.... So the proxy files are DIFFERENT named files with content that is dynamically provided by simply getting the first n lines of the main file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hacky, but... One way is to use named pipes, and a looping shell script to generate the content (one per named pipe). This script would look like:

```
while true; do
    (
        for $(seq linenr); do echo something; done
    ) >thenamedpipe;
done
```

Your script would then read from that named pipe.

Another solution, if you are ready to dig into low level stuff, is FUSE.

Comment: Okay... it seems like you've provided two answers here --- but I think the clarification of "at least not with the same name" confuses your otherwise  excellent answer.  Not sure what your referring to... why would I want the files to have the same name ?

Comment: That is, your first version of the text. Now I see that this is not a requirement. Editing.